# remembered() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to increment a value through a button click. But I get the error

```
remembered() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Which I don't understand, because as far as I can see the function remembered() needs both the PK's I send it.

Urls

```
 path('mypage/<int:pk>/', DeckDetailView.as_view(),name='mypage-study-deck'),
 path('mypage/<int:pk>/<int:card_id>', views.remembered, name='remembered')
```

Views

```
class DeckDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Deck

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        deck = self.get_object()
        deck_title = deck.title
        context = super(DeckDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['cards'] = Card.objects.filter(
            decks__title=deck_title).filter(days_till_study=1)
        return context


def remembered(request, card_id, deck_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        deck = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=deck_id)
        card = get_object_or_404(Card, pk=card_id)
        card.days_till_study = card.days_till_study * 2
        card.save()
        return redirect('/mypage/' + str(deck.id))
```

Template

```
{% for card in cards reversed %}
<div class="my-column
col-xl-4 mt-2 ">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"> {{card.question}} </h5>
    <p class="card-text">  </p>
    <a href="{% url 'mypage-study-deck' deck.id %}">
      <!--                           Here we add the collapse functionality for the button -->
      <p>
        <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{card.id}}"  role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{card.id}}">
          See Answer
        </a>
      </p>
      <div class="collapse" id="{{card.id}}">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <p> {{card.answer}} </p>
          <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('remembered').submit()}">
            <div class="btn btn-success"> Remembered </div>
            <!-- Days to study should be incremented - I need to get some post up in here?-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form id="remembered" method="POST" action="{% url 'remembered' deck.id card.id  %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type ="hidden">
  </form>

  {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Django passes to the view function the arguments from route, in this case `mypage/<int:pk>/<int:card_id>`, and the argument names here are `pk` and `card_id` so this is where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you pass `pk` and `card_id` through url. But in view you not consider the order of the passed data. So lets try this.

```
def remembered(request,pk,card_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        deck = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=pk)
        card = get_object_or_404(Card, pk=card_id)
        card.days_till_study = card.days_till_study * 2
        card.save()
        return redirect('/mypage/' + str(deck.id))
```

Comment: Are you check this answer  ??. i updated 1 hour ago.

Comment: Works. Fantastic. Thank you.